# What's the meaning of these numbers in geometric distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, python

For a geometric distribution, I know there's a certain pattern, for example, given the probability of success $0.2$ for a event, you can have:

$$P(X = r) = {q}^{(r-1)} \times p$$

- When r = 1, probability is 0.2
- When r = 2, probability is 0.32
- When r = 3, probability is 0.128
- So on..

This tells me the probability of trial 1, 2, 3 .. and I can see it decreases for every trial.

I tried to do this same example using code to generate data for geometric distribution using python programming language:

```
s = np.random.geometric(p, 100000)
```

It means for 'p' = 0.20, give me 100,000 samples.

Here are 500 samples from these and what they look like:

[1, 6, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 5, 3, 9, 12, 6, 2, 7, 3, 7, 7, 4, 2, 4, 4, 1, 2, 9, 3, 9, 1, 5, 9, 1, 10, 7, 8, 2, 1, 6, 1, 8, 1, 5, 2, 2, 7, 4, 3, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5, 4, 1, 9, 1, 7, 6, 2, 7, 13, 24, 1, 3, 2, 2, 8, 2, 1, 2, 8, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 12, 7, 5, 14, 6, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 4, 1, 12, 2, 7, 18, 8, 6, 5, 5, 6, 2, 12, 4, 1, 1, 2, 5, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 12, 6, 7, 5, 9, 3, 12, 3, 5, 9, 7, 3, 8, 3, 12, 2, 27, 2, 7, 2, 14, 3, 2, 5, 5, 9, 1, 1, 12, 6, 1, 12, 14, 4, 2, 7, 25, 7, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 10, 2, 4, 1, 6, 11, 2, 12, 5, 5, 14, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 10, 8, 6, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 14, 13, 2, 3, 2, 8, 8, 5, 6, 2, 6, 1, 5, 2, 12, 1, 6, 1, 3, 12, 9, 6, 4, 1, 4, 6, 16, 8, 3, 3, 4, 1, 7, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 7, 2, 5, 3, 7, 8, 6, 3, 7, 2, 8, 2, 1, 1, 4, 9, 2, 5, 4, 2, 10, 1, 10, 6, 10, 1, 6, 2, 3, 14, 2, 1, 10, 4, 2, 11, 6, 10, 6, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 9, 19, 1, 2, 17, 1, 6, 7, 12, 4, 15, 11, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 31, 2, 22, 6, 2, 4, 10, 1, 1, 3, 9, 3, 4, 4, 15, 8, 5, 1, 1, 18, 2, 3, 2, 1, 11, 5, 8, 8, 2, 8, 4, 7, 3, 2, 5, 1, 8, 2, 20, 1, 8, 2, 1, 4, 4, 3, 5, 2, 5, 2, 1, 1, 9, 3, 6, 11, 2, 5, 7, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 1, 3, 7, 2, 6, 4, 4, 9, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 7, 7, 1, 3, 2, 2, 21, 4, 1, 12, 7, 4, 7, 5, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 16, 21, 7, 2, 9, 3, 4, 2, 6, 9, 2, 1, 1, 32, 5, 3, 5, 2, 5, 4, 5, 1, 2, 7, 4, 18, 12, 3, 2, 4, 12, 10, 5, 8, 3, 1, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 22, 7, 2, 16, 5, 9, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 3, 7, 7, 4, 14, 9, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 1, 7, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 19, 2, 2, 17, 4, 4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 3, 5, 5, 2, 6, 1, 8, 6, 1, 1, 2, 6, 11, 3, 3, 6, 9, 4, 8, 1, 9, 6, 3, 8, 9, 5, 11, 2, 1, 3, 1, 6, 3, 1]

What I want to know is that how these numbers represent geometric distribution? Is there a certain order? The probability of say, 0, 1, 2, or 3 appearing as next number? Does the order matter at all?

Comment: The relative frequencies of these sample will converge to the true pmf of the underlying geometric distribution.

Comment: Assuming your pseudorandom number generator works to make these look independent, there is no additional information in the order, and any other order of the same numbers would be equally likely.

Comment: You could say you expect in this case about $\frac{499}{9}\approx 55.4$ values equal to their preceding values.  You actually have $51$ such cases - close enough

Comment: @Henry: This [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/498552/256926) has an answer which seems to say order does matter. Would you agree with it?

Comment: I read @tommik 's answer as saying "there is no order, correlation or dependence in those numbers"

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your data, you generated random numbers from a geometric distribution counting the failures before first success

$$P(X=x)=0.8^x\cdot 0.2$$

$x=0;1;2...$

If you do the average of the generated numbers you have to find 4 and a variance of 20. Thus it is difficult that your sample comes from a $Geo(0.2)$

No, there is no order, correlation or dependence in those numbers (I hope, if the random generating algorithm works well)

You can use particular statistical methods to generate this sample by your own

Comment: I edited and pasted the correct numbers, I had them wrong. So, is there really no order and it means from order we can't say it is geometric distribution?

Comment: @user963241 : first check average and variance: 5 and 20 respectively...

Comment: Yes, average and variance are correct as you say. If we look at first 5 numbers say [1, 6, 1, 2, 3].. what does this 1 represent and 6 so on?

Comment: @user963241 they represent the number of trial you need to get the first success. For example: toss $n$ times a biased coin with probability of H=0.2, the numbers are the trials you need to get the first H

Comment: Sounds interesting.. So I tossed this biased coin say, $100,000$ times and each one of these $100,000$ numbers is number of trials it took to get head?

Comment: @user963241: yes, to get the first head

Comment: Is there a second head too?

Comment: add pairs of consecutive values together to get the number of attempts for two successes, representing [one version of the negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Alternative_formulations).